# display each record of list into a separate line in jython

Tags: list, jython

how to display record of the list in different line

```
['0 , INDIVS08 , ODI_TEMP', '1 , C$_0EMPLOYEES , ODI_TEMP', '2 , C$_0PACS08 , ODI_TEMP']
```

i want to display as

```
'0 , INDIVS08 , ODI_TEMP' ,
'1 , C$_0EMPLOYEES , ODI_TEMP',
'2 , C$_0PACS08 , ODI_TEMP'
```

Thanks for all of your help

Answer (score 0):

```
lst = ['0 , INDIVS08 , ODI_TEMP', '1 , C$_0EMPLOYEES , ODI_TEMP', '2 , C$_0PACS08 , ODI_TEMP']
print(',\n'.join(["'%s'" % s for s in lst]))
```

`',\n'.join()` joins list, so it will be printed in separate lines with ending with comma.

`["'%s'" % s for s in lst]` is a little compilated, but it adds `'` for every item in `lst`.